# Choose one entry from a list if its key contains a string from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question regarding my dataframe. Specifically, in one column, for each row, I have a list of speakers and speeches. Now, I want to choose exactly one speech, based on whether the speaker is the one I am looking for, which is noted within another column. So one column provides the last name I am looking for and the other column provides a list of all speakers (first and last name) and their speech and I want to create a new columns where this speech is stored in the respective row.

So my initial dataset looks like this:

```
ticker  year    quarter exel_lname  jobposition speech
xx      2009    1       Angle       CEO         [("Mike Angle", "Thank you"), ("Barbara Barth", "It is")]
xx      2009    1       Barth       CFO         [("Mike Angle", "Thank you"), ("Barbara Barth", "It is")]
xx      2009    2       Angle       CEO         [("Mike Angle", "I am surprised"), ("Barbara Barth", "So am I")]
xx      2009    2       Barth       CFO         [("Mike Angle", "I am surprised"), ("Barbara Barth", "So am I")]
yy      2008    3       Cruz        CEO         [("Damien Cruz", "Hello"), ("Lara Dolm", "Nice to meet you")]
yy      2008    3       Dolm        CFO         [("Damien Cruz", "Hello"), ("Lara Dolm", "Nice to meet you")]
```

For row one for instance, I want to check each key-value pair whether the first list entry contains the last name, if no continue, if yes, take the speech part (i.e. second list entry) and store it in new column. As such, I want the following dataset (I hid the initial column speech here, but it should still be contained, so I do not want to replace it, just create a new column).

```
ticker  year    quarter exel_lname  jobposition speechmanager
xx      2009    1       Angle       CEO         "Thank you"
xx      2009    1       Barth       CFO         "It is"
xx      2009    2       Angle       CEO         "I am surprised"
xx      2009    2       Barth       CFO         "So am I"
yy      2008    3       Cruz        CEO         "Hello"
yy      2008    3       Dolm        CFO         "Nice to meet you"
```

Could someone help me how to solve this in Python 3?

Thank you!!
Julia

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps best accomplished by writting a function, and then applying it row-wise:

```
def get_speech(row):
    matches = list(filter(lambda x: x[0].endswith(row['exel_lname']), row['speech']))
    if len(matches) > 0:
        return matches[0][1]
    return ''

df['speechmanager'] = df.apply(get_speech, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I somehow got: "('list index out of range', 'occurred at index 0')" back. Could maybe something like:                                                        def f(L):
    res1 = defaultdict(list)
    for item in df["exec_lname"]:
        for v,k in L:
            1st approach: new=[k for k in L if item in v]
            2nd approach: if any(item in v for v in L):
                new = list({key for key, value in res1}.items().items())
                return new
      df["speechmanager"]=df["speech"].apply(f)
or something similar work? Or why could list index be out of range?

Comment: @Julia the `[0]` index would be out of range if the list comprehension returned an empty list, which I didn't initially account for; I modified the answer so that the comprehension returns the second item of the first tuple that matches, if one matches, or returns an empty string if there is no match.

Comment: Thanks - it now works for some observations - only for those where the first tuple is also the one where item[0] ends with the last name. If the person is not the first speaker and thus his speech appears in another tuple, an empty string is returned. Is there a way to make Python continue search through all tuples?

Comment: @Julia apologies, that’s my mistake -- the correct logic will work best if written into a multi-line function. Please see the changes to the answer and let me know if you have questions or problems.

Comment: It still didn't work. I get the mistake "object of type 'filter' has no len()", 'occurred at index 0'). So the one before already worked for some observations... if it could just go through all tuples, it would have worked perfectly. For this one, I could somehow not even generate the new column... I hope you can help me, thank you for your effort!

Comment: And now we've come across a difference between Python 2 and 3 :). I was working in 2.7; in Python 3, `filter` is a generator, and thus in this case should be wrapped in `list()`.

Comment: I have a follow-up question to this... how would the code change if I had a list of the CEO and CFO name (managernames) and would want to get a cell for the speech of all managers where they are added together, so for ticker xx 2009 q1, the speechmanager cell for the CEO is "Thank you" and the speechmanagers cell is "Thank you It is"... so that the code runs through a list of all managers and adds all their speech parts together. I know I could just now add the strings together in a next step, but I would be interested in how to do it directly with a code running through the list...? Thanks!!